# Cannot cast back to ICollection<T>

Tags: c#

I have an Interface `ISomeThing`:

```
public interface ISomeThing {}
```

and 2 types implementing it:

```
public class SomeThing1 : ISomeThing {}

public class SomeThing2 : ISomeThing {}
```

and then I have a type using those types:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public ICollection<SomeThing1> Foo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SomeThing2> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I then have to use reflection to get access to the properties of `FooBar`:

```
var properties = typeof(FooBar).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
Console.WriteLine(properties.Count());
```

The output will be `0`. Even if I change the code to look for `ICollection<ISomeThing>` it won't work:

```
var properties = typeof(FooBar).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => typeof(ICollection<ISomeThing>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
Console.WriteLine(properties.Count());
```

I want to get access to the property directly because `ICollection` brings in `Remove` etc.. So I need the cast to `ICollection<T>`.

**Edit**

I changed my sample to use `ISomeThing` instead of `DateTime`. The point is that I don't know the exact generic type at runtime but I need to yield a `ICollection<ISomeThing>` as the result.

** Edit 2 **

Now I finally come up with my example. This example here shows why I need the cast so badly.

```
var properties = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties){
    var value = property.GetValue(instance);
    if (value is ISomeThing someThingValue && someThingValue.IsSomeCondition)
    {
        // Do a ISomeThing-specific thing here
    }
    else if (property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Concat(new []{property.PropertyType})
        .Any(i => i.IsGenericType 
              && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
              && typeof(ISomeThing).IsAssignableFrom(i.GetGenericArguments().Single())))
    {
        var someThingValues = value as ICollection<ISomeThing>; // <-- this results in null
        foreach (var someThingInstance in someThingValues)
        {
            if(someThingInstance.IsSomeCondition)
            {
                // Do the thing again
            }
        }
    }
    // Enter recursion for possible nested ISomeThings
}
```

Comment: I know! Entity Framwork 6 does exactly this in my case. It generates `ICollection<T>` and initializes them as `HashTable<T>` in the constructor.

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry I oversaw it during my first edit.

Comment: @MichaelGunter I changed the complete question now.

Comment: Good updates. But more questions: You say "I then have to use reflection to get access to the properties of FooBar". Why?  You wrote the class `FooBar`; you already know what all of its properties are.

Comment: Is the question "Given a `Type`, I wish to know how many properties are of type `ICollection<T>` where `T` is any type that implements `ISomeThing`" ?  Because that code is a little tricky to write but totally doable.

Comment: Or is it how many properties are of type `X` where `X` is any type that implements any `ICollection<T>` where `T` is convertible to `ISomeType`?

Comment: @EricLippert Your suggestion already helped out. I know added the actual code including some comments what goes wrong. Hopefully you can see now why I need to cast to `ICollection`.

Comment: I don't see why you need to cast it to `ICollection`. You need to cast it to `IEnumerable`.  I'll make an update to my answer.

Comment: Also, what you are doing is called "XY questions".  You want to know how to do X, you have some crazy idea that Y works, Y doesn't work, and so you ask "why doesn't Y work?" and then when you get an answer to that, you're no closer to solving X.  Your original question was "why is this null?" but knowing that does not solve your actual problem. Then your update was "how to count properties of a certain type?", which also doesn't solve the problem.  **Stop doing that**. It is very frustrating for the people trying to help you to constantly have the question change every time it gets an answer.

Comment: I think all the question's update are just more detailed additions to show the actual use-case. The original question/title is about casting to `ICollection<T>`, which isn't solved.
I'm not entirely sure, if the workaround with `IEnumerable` will work here, as @sprinter252 stated in the original question:
 "I want to get access to the property directly because `ICollection` brings in `Remove` etc.. So I need the cast to `ICollection<T>`"
Also I still wonder why the cast to `IEnumerable<T>` works, when the cast to `ICollection<T>` does not. The actual type is `HashSet`, which implements both

Comment: @Nasto: See my comment to your comment on my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @Nasto: If calling `Remove` is important then (1) that should be in the example, and (2) **you can't call remove from inside a foreach loop**, so the code sample is wrong *again*, or there is a larger problem to solve that was never stated before.  You can't modify a collection while it is being enumerated; collections are supposed to throw if that happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ICollection<DateTime> collection = new HashSet<ISomeThing>();
```

That makes no sense. I assume you meant to type

```
ICollection<ISomeThing> collection = new HashSet<ISomeThing>();
```

Moving on.

```
Console.WriteLine(collection.GetType() as ICollection<ISomeThing>);
```

This is null because `collection.GetType()` returns a `Type`, and a `Type` does not implement `ICollection<ISomething>`.

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(ICollection<>)
    .IsAssignableFrom(collection.GetType()));
```

This is false because `IsAssignableFrom` means "can a variable of type `ICollection<>` be assigned a value of type `HashSet<ISomething>`.  There is no such thing as a variable of type `ICollection<>`. Generic types have to be constructed before they can be the type of a variable.

> I feel almost like the output lies to me when I look at line 1 and 3

It does not.

> but I want to get access to the property directly because `ICollection` brings in `Remove` etc. So I need the cast to `ICollection<T>`.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what this sentence means. Can you clarify it?

---

UPDATE:

Based on the update to the question I now suspect that the actual question is either

> Given a `Type`, I wish to know how many properties are of type `ICollection<T>` where `T` is any type that implements `ISomeThing`"

Easy peasy:

```
Type type = typeof(FooBar);
var properties = type
  .GetProperties()
  .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
  .Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
  .Where(p => typeof(ISomeThing).IsAssignableFrom(
    p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Single()))
Console.WriteLine(properties.Count()); // 2
```

or perhaps it is

> Given a `Type`, I wish to know how many properties are of types that *implement* `ICollection<T>` where `T` is any type that implements `ISomeThing`"

That would be

```
    var properties = type
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType
          .GetInterfaces()
          .Concat(new [] {p.PropertyType})
          .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
          .Where(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
          .Where(i => typeof(ISomeThing)
            .IsAssignableFrom(i.GetGenericArguments().Single()))
          .Any());
```

---

UPDATE: Based on the latest update to this confusing question, the question is now how to rewrite this loop so that it works:

```
{
    var someThingValues = value as ICollection<ISomeThing>; // <-- this results in null
    foreach (var someThingInstance in someThingValues)
    {
        if(someThingInstance.IsSomeCondition)
        {
            // Do the thing again
        }
    }
}
```

That's easy. You simply don't attempt to cast to `ICollection<anything>` because you don't need any member of that type in your example. What do we know? That the type is `ICollection<T>` where `T` is `ISomeThing`. It is a *requirement* that this type implements non-generic `IEnumerable` and generic `IEnumerable<T>`.

It is **not** a requirement that the `IEnumerable` only yield objects that implement `ISomeThing`, but the author of the object would be *crazy* to have `IEnumerable` yield different objects than could be in the collection, so let's be cautious and stick a type filter on there.

```
var properties = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties){
    // Let's emphasize here that we don't know the type by using
    // object instead of var
    object value = property.GetValue(instance);

    // We need to bail if this is null.
    if (value == null)   
      continue;

    if (value is ISomeThing someThingValue && someThingValue.IsSomeCondition)
    {
        // Do a ISomeThing-specific thing here
    }
    else if (property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Concat(new []{property.PropertyType})
        .Any(i => i.IsGenericType 
              && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
              && typeof(ISomeThing).IsAssignableFrom(i.GetGenericArguments().Single())))
    {
        var ie = value as IEnumerable;
        Debug.Assert(ie != null);
        foreach (ISomeThing someThingInstance in ie.OfType<ISomeThing>())
        {
            if(someThingInstance.IsSomeCondition)
            {
                // Do the thing again
            }
        }
    }
    // Enter recursion for possible nested ISomeThings
}
```

You could also tighten that up a bit with

```
        var q = ie.OfType<ISomeThing>().
           .Where(x => x.IsSomeCondition);
        foreach (ISomeThing someThingInstance in q)
        {
                // Do the thing again
        }
```

---

BONUS EXERCISE

Now, one might reasonable note that `ICollection<T>` is also convertible to `IEnumerable<T>`.  We could reason like this:

- We know we have `ICollection<T>` for some `T` that implements `ISomeThing`.
- We know that we can convert `ICollection<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` for any `T`.
- Therefore we can convert this to `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T` that implements `ISomeThing`.
- `IEnumerable<T>` is *covariant in `T`* and therefore we can convert our `ICollection<T>` directly to `IEnumerable<ISomeThing>` and enumerate that.
- Therefore we should really be writing

---

```
var ie = value as IEnumerable<ISomeThing>;    
Debug.Assert(ie != null);
foreach (ISomeThing someThingInstance in ie)
```

---

**The above argument contains a logical flaw**.  Do you see it?

Give it some thought and once you figure out why this logic is wrong, leave an answer in the comments.

Comment: What I mean with that sentence is that I need to return an ICollection afterall. I recognized that it'll find my property when I search for an `IEnumerable<ISomeThing>` but the result has no `Remove` method then which I need in my case.

Comment: So you are able to do a cast like `value as IEnumerable<ISomeThing>` but not a cast like `value as ICollection<ISomeThing>`? Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Comment: @Nasto: `IEnumerable<T>` is *covariant in T* but `ICollection<T>` is not.  The reason is:  a bowl of apples is not a bowl of fruit. You can put a banana into a bowl of fruit but you cannot put a banana into a bowl of apples, so they are different.  **A collection allows you to modify its contents** so it is like a bowl of apples -- you cannot change it into a collection of *less specific type* because then you could put a wrong objects into the collection.  But `IEnumerable<T>` has no method that allows you to insert a `T`, so it can safely vary.  Do a search on "C# covariance" for details.

Comment: @EricLippert That last comment cleared it out to me now.

Comment: @sprinter252: I've added an exercise to see if you understand why the right solution is not to use covariance on `IEnumerable<T>` to go directly to `IEnumerable<ISomeThing>`.  Do you see why that goes wrong?  HINT: What do you know about covariant conversions?

Comment: `if (value is ISomeThing someThingValue && someThingValue.IsSomeCondition)` — Has C# 7 gotten `is` and `as` combined into a single bottle and is that the syntax for it?

Comment: @Joker_vD: It has, and it is.

Comment: @EricLippert still thinking about the logical excercise. I‘m slow :(

Comment: @sprinter252: Big hint: Under exactly what circumstances is `IEnumerable<Something>` convertible to `IEnumerable<ISomething>` ?

Answer (score -1):

With the updated example, this should get you what you want. It finds all properties that are of `ICollection<>` and have a generic parameter that implements `ISomeThing`.

```
var properties = typeof(FooBar).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>) && p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISomeThing)));
```